# Getting Fatal Exception

Tags: android, android-camera

hi while clicking on button my application is crashing with below error message ::

```
 W/dalvikvm(15165): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:501)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.app.ContextImpl.setWallpaper(ContextImpl.java:616)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.setWallpaper(ContextWrapper.java:243)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at com.thenewboston.travis.Camera.onClick(Camera.java:47)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15165):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and **Camera.java**
    package com.thenewboston.travis;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageButton ib;
    ImageView iv;
    Button b;
    Intent i;
    Bitmap bmp;
    final static int cameraData = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo);
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        ib.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.imageButton1 :
            try {
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.button1:
            i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
            break;

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle ext = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap)ext.get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are trying to get ImageView and ImageButton with Same ID

i.e

```
 ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
 iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

Both have same ID `R.id.imageButton1`

So You'll get your imageview NULL which cause NullPoinerException.

Try to change the ID of imageview

Comment: +1 Good catch, but this won't fix the current errors. :( (Also are you quoting yourself?)

Comment: @Sam Thanks and good to get appreciation from one of favourites in SO

Comment: @Sam "Also are you quoting yourself?" Sorry I don't know, still I have limited knowledge on what is what in SO.. If I did wrong please correct it

Comment: The `>` is used for block quotes but you used it on "You are trying to get ImageView and ImageButton with Same ID".  Are you trying to highlight this sentence?

Comment: I clicked ImageButton before Button

Comment: @Sam yes.. Seriously I have found that today itself...is it wrong to use that..means will it going to give different meaning.. sorry for my english

Comment: It should only be used to quote something, not as emphasis (highlighting).  You can find other tricks in the [Editing Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Don't worry if your English is perfect or not, as long as your code is good.  We all speak Android. :)

Answer (score 1):

The LogCat shows that `bmp` is null in:

```
getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
```

It looks like you clicked `ib` before `b`.  The only place that you instantiate `bmp` is in `onActivityResult()` and only then if the user selected an image.  You can change the `ib` Button's visibility in `onActivityResult()` to only be shown when there is a valid Bitmap to use.

Also please read [Pragnani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15644961/1267661) he has a great observation, though it might not cause this exception since ImageButton is a subclass of ImageView.

Comment: I think you deserve this answer...He may mistakely accepted my answer...but +1 for the answer